# custom fast cgi cache duration for a location

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi

i have this configure

```
location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass phpstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_cache GCache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 120m;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
}
```

i wanna make the duration dynamic for some locations instead of `120m` for all so i tried

```
location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass phpstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        set $duration = 120m;
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/([0-9]+)/$) { 
            set $duration 30s;
        }

        fastcgi_cache GCache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 $duration;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
}
```

but i get error

```
2022/08/21 22:11:12 [emerg] 1#1: invalid time value "$duration" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/data.conf
nginx: [emerg] invalid time value "$duration" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/data.conf
```

i wanna make it 30s for dynamic content so it updates every 30s if the dynamic content updated but the rest is different

Comment: `fastcgi_cache_valid` does not accept variables as its value.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin can not be done around it maybe all of it in condition?